# Analyze a large heap dump on command line?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-dump

I have a legacy application whose GC logs show frequent allocation failures repeatedly.(GC mode is Concurrent Mark Sweep)
The heap dump is large (~7.5G).Is there a way to analyze the heap dump file from command line?( To do it in a remote ssh session without downloading large heap dump to a local machine,X11 port forwarding is not enabled)

In my understanding the below logs suggest that there are a lot of new objects being created and getting garbage collected.I have the heap dump file.I tried Jhat which took too long with no response and MAT which went out of memory even with Xmx 6g.
Any suggestions on how can I find the culprit object?

Below is snippet of the log

> 2015-12-09T21:07:32.911+0000: 29565.425: [GC (Allocation Failure)
>   29565.425: [ParNew: 383424K->42560K(383424K), 1.4270759 secs] 4776398K->4744049K(6248896K), 1.4273264 secs] [Times: user=2.54
>   sys=0.00, real=1.42 secs] 2015-12-09T21:07:34.338+0000: 29566.852:
>   Total time for which application threads were stopped: 1.4381753
>   seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0098894 seconds
>   2015-12-09T21:07:34.339+0000: 29566.853: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1
>   CMS-initial-mark: 4701489K(5865472K)] 4746653K(6248896K), 0.0663050
>   secs] [Times: user=0.09 sys=0.00, real=0.07 secs]
>   2015-12-09T21:07:34.406+0000: 29566.920: Total time for which
>   application threads were stopped: 0.0672519 seconds, Stopping threads
>   took: 0.0000681 seconds

Comment: MAT is the way to go for heap dump analysis of large heaps. I think you should be able to analyze a 7.5G heap with with 6G heap assigned to MAT. Are you sure you are setting Xmx correctly for MAT? If possible try to increase the Xmx for MAT a bit more and hope for success. I have several times analysed 10G heaps with 10G assigned to MAT, but of course, behavior can very depending on heap contents.

Comment: Not exactly an out of box tool, but that is how I was analyzing 150GiB heap dump on remote server http://blog.ragozin.info/2015/02/programatic-heapdump-analysis.html